# render contents dynamically in react native Swiper

Tags: ios, mobile, react-native

I am trying to render product image and its description as slider using react native swiper. But is it possible to render dynamic content in react native swiper.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do this but the issue is that the **height of every slide is fixed** which is taken from longest slide height and applied to all  other slides